# Should the changes of SymfonyRequirements.php be included in version control?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.7

After running `composer update`, I got `app/SymfonyRequirements.php` is updated in my working changes of my symfony 2.7@beta application. What is that file? Should I commit the changes of the file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The files is used in the `check` CLI tool that [use](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.8/app/check.php#L6) this files for control the minimal Requirements for Running Symfony. You can find more info [in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html).

Usually is take into account in a version control system, as you can see in the symfony-standard distribution project on github:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard

(of course you can add the files in your custom .gitignore files)

Hope this help

Comment: I originally added it in version control and so it has been tracked. Is it safe to remove from the tracked file list?

Comment: is not your code so you don't need to version it. You can always take the new file update via `composer update` and you can execute the check too without problem. BTW I always take into version control.