# New files on installation of project Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I've installed a Symfony project on Windows (developed on a Mac) and after `composer install` I got 3 new files :

- bin/symfony_requirements
- var/SymfonyRequirements.php
- web/config.php

Do I need to version those files or ignore them in the `.gitignore` file ?

Comment: you find answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315225/why-is-symfonyrequirements-php-excluded-from-gitignore) you can ignore or version these files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should the changes of SymfonyRequirements.php be included in version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30700635/should-the-changes-of-symfonyrequirements-php-be-included-in-version-control)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- web/config.php

From SensioLabsInsight,

> This `config.php` file should only be used to bootstrap a Symfony application. Before releasing to production, you should remove it, otherwise attackers could get valuable insight about your application.

- var/SymfonyRequirements.php

This file is used by Symfony Check CLI Script to check for minimum requirements of configuring & running a Symfony App. It's a Common Post-Deployment Task.

See this question [Should the changes of SymfonyRequirements.php be included in version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30700635/should-the-changes-of-symfonyrequirements-php-be-included-in-version-control) and the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html).

Answer (score 1):

No need to add these files in git.

I use `.gitignore` as like this and its working fine for me and my team.

```
/web/assetic/
/web/bundles/*
/var/bootstrap.php.cache
/var/cache/*
/var/sessions/*
/app/config/parameters.yml
/var/logs/*
/vendor/
/bin/
/web/uploads/
/.project
/.buildpath
/.settings
```